# Select MySQL Tables with less than 100k Rows

Tags: mysql

I'd like to be able to make a backup of tables with less than 100K rows.  What I'm trying to do is clone a development database to my local machine that has many log tables that I don't need the data for, and tables with "legitimate" content.

So I'm going to have one dump that just copies the structures of the tables, and another, that copies the relevant data from these tables with less than 100k rows.

If I have to use an intermediary language like Python or PHP, I'm fine with that.

edit: So the question is, how do I create a mysql dump of data from tables with less than 100k rows?

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: Do you want all tables (including the log tables) in your develepoment database and have a maximum number of 100k entries per table or do you only want the tables that currently have less than 100k entries?

Comment: @OcasoProtal I'd rather not have any log data whatsoever carried over, so only data from the tables with less than 100k entries.  LightnessRacesinOrbit lol that was actually funny, edited for your benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe something like this

```
mysql databasename -u [root] -p[password] —disable-column-names -e 
    'select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_rows < 100000;'
    | xargs mysqldump [databasename] -u [root] -p[password] > [target_file]
```

p.s. all this will need to be in a single line

Comment: p.s2: or just put \ on every line end

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, xargs complained about the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To dump only the schema

```
mysqldump --user=dbuser --password --no-data --tab=/tmp dbname
```

or try to export schema and data seperately for each table with below command

```
mysqldump --user=dbuser --password --tab=/tmp dbname
```

Or

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 100000" database > fileName.sql
```

that would give you the 100K rows from every table.

To Ignore some tables

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 100000" --ignore-table=database.table1 
--ignore-table=database.table2 database > fileName.sql
```

Comment: Bad solution, since he doesn't want some tables at all and you don't know how much DROP TABLE statements he would have to execute thereafter.